# Flutter create a custom DropDown Menue below a button

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

I am trying to build a *custom* `DropDownButton` but I am quite stuck...
I tried it by having a simple `button` and by tapping that it opens a `AnimatedContainer` right below it. The problem is that the `AnimatedContainer` is actually taking the place below the `DropDownButton`, but instead it should *cover* the everything below it.

[image][image]

As you can see the orange DropDown appears correctly but it pushes the items below it towards the bottom.

```
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double _dropDownHeight =
        dropDownOptions.length < 4 ? dropDownOptions.length * 50 : 200;
    return Column(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => setState(
            () => {
              _isOpen = !_isOpen,
            },
          ),
          child: Container(
            height: scaleWidth(50),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: AppColors.black),
              ),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: scaleWidth(10),
                ),
                Text(
                  selectedOption ?? placeholerTitle,
                  style: AppTextStyles.h5Light,
                ),
                Spacer(),
                _isOpen
                    ? SvgPicture.asset(
                        'images/icons/arrow_down_primary.svg',
                        width: scaleWidth(21),
                      )
                    : SvgPicture.asset(
                        'images/icons/arrow_up_primary.svg',
                        width: scaleWidth(21),
                      ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: scaleWidth(10),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        AnimatedContainer(
          height: _isOpen ? _dropDownHeight : 0,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return DropDownItem(
                  index: index,
                  title: dropDownOptions[index],
                );
              },
              itemCount: dropDownOptions.length,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I feel like I am approaching this the wrong way... I need some way to let the `dropDownMenue` appear above everything else but I could not figure that out. Can anyone help me out here?

Let me know if you need any more details.